# Accessing SQL Server from outside of the domain with Windows authentication and ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, odbc

I have a machine with Windows Server, some users defined in its Active Directory and a SQL Server that grants permission to some of those user to a database. I can connect from a machine in the same domain to that database using Windows authentication and ODBC in C++.

Is it possible to connect from a machine outside of that domain? Which connection string should I use?